# Facing issues in IBM MQ testing using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am working on IBM MQ Performance testing using JMeter. Currently while executing the script i am facing error message. I am able to connect this IBM MQ using RHF utility manually. But in JMeter, i am getting below error. May i know how to fix this error.

Error :

Response message:javax.script.ScriptException: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'CLDACEAPD' with connection mode 'Client' and host name '172.XX.XX.XX(1414)'.
Check the queue manager is started and if running in client mode, check there is a listener running. Please see the linked exception for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), the full exception details should be there, look for the string which starts with `Caused by` and see what is the real cause of the issue.

If it's not there surround your code which establishes the connection with the queue manager into [try block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) and populate the catch block as follows:

```
try {
    //your code here
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    log.error('Failed to connect to IBMMQ instance', ex)
}
```

Additional logging for IBMMQ client can be enabled by setting the following [system properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization):

```
com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.status=ON
com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.level=9
com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.outputName=/path/to/ibbmq/client.log
```

Comment: Sure. Thanks Dmitri. this will help.